# Comparison of assessments of cognitive skills in children

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, developmental-psychology, test, educational-psychology

What test is better in terms of its usability and informativeness - WISC-IV (Wechsler Intelligence Scale for Children) or BAS (British Ability Scales)?

Comment: Questions in regards to personal or professional experience are generally discouraged on Stackexchange sites. However, encouraging an answer comprehensively evaluating both sides with citations of other evaluations/surveys is acceptable. Consequently, I've removed the preamble to your question. However, welcome to Cogsci.SE! We're really happy to have new professionals join our site!

Comment: Dear Seanny123, thank you very much for clarifying the specificity of Stackexchange usage for me. I am sorry I brought some troubles here.